# Identity Server 4 with refresh token and External Provider + Refresh token

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

my system is composed of several entities

- IS - an identity provider (Identity Server 4)
- C  - an hybrid client with refresh_token
- EP - OAuth 2.0 external provider

  1. When a user tries to log in C, he is redirected to IS
  2. Once in IS, he presses EP and sign in with his credentials
  3. using *EP_code_grant*, the IS can get an *EP_access_token+EP_refresh_token*
  4. upon getting and parsing these, IS now trusts the user and generates a pair *IS_access_token+IS_refresh_token* so the user can access client C

So far, so good

**my problem is when the EP entity disables the user on his system**, my user will still be logged for *IS_access_token* lifetime and will use *IS_refresh_token* to generate new *IS_access_tokens*. therefore, *potentially*, the user will never be logged out from the system (only when *refresh_token* expires... and that can be for a long time)

Any suggestions?

My current idea is to store the *EP_access_token+EP_refresh_token* in a custom cookie, and before using *IS_refresh_token*, get a **new** *EP_access_token+EP_refresh_token* using *EP_refresh_token*, therefore, if the EP can actually emit a new *EP_access_token+EP_refresh_token* then it is safe to generate a new *IS_access_token+IS_refresh_token* using *IS_refresh_token*

If this is possible, how can I do this in Identity Server 4?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all - are you sure that your client is Implicit? According to the official documentation http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/refresh_tokens.html, this is not quite possible.

Comment: you are quite right, client grant type is hybrid, but that is beyond the point and i am currently using refresh tokens

Comment: Yes, correct. So your problem is the cookie life time. I guess that when you close and open the browser the problem is gone (your user is forced to login again). What do you mean by `EP entity disables the user on his system`? And admin deleting/lowering the permissions of a user?

Comment: Not quite. Let us say EP is google. If a user uses Google to sign in on my system, everything is fine. Then, a while later, the user deletes the google account, therefore, he cannot request more tokens to google (EP). Eventually, the access_token for my system turns invalid (lifetime), and I use my refresh token to get a new pair. Doing this does not require to go to Google, so my system generates a new pair. What I want is, when generating this new pair, I should also verify that the user exists and is valid to get tokens in Google (EP). Hope it clarifies a bit

Comment: OK this really got my interest. According to the docs (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout_federated.html) this is already implemented on the Identity Server side, so all that you need to do is to configure your **EP** and also it should support this functionality.